# meet a link error while building opengl project on win7 with visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

The compile all goes well. However, when it goes to the link stage, error comes out:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ptrc_glClear
```

There're also many other errors with the same link error, including _ptr_glViewport, _ptr_glDrawArrays......
I'm searched in stackoverflow, and find many questions about the link problem of opengl32.lib. I followed their advice, but still it doesn't work.
I also notice that, the problems occurred in others' question([error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339444/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol)), appear to be somewhat different: what they failed to link is with the prefix "**imp**", while mine is "*ptr*".
I wonder, is the problem of the "_ptrc_xxxxx" thing also comes with the opengl32.lib, or did I miss some other libs to link?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any kind of OpenGL loader library (GLee, GLEW, glLoadGen)? Prefixed OpenGL symbols are usually imposed on your source code by including such a loaders header (which uses some preprocessor magic to turn all OpenGL symbols in your code into symbols referring to the loader). If then your program fails to link with that very loader you'll get these unresolved symbol linker errors.

Comment: I use GLFW. I have linked the glfw3.lib into the project, but still the problem exists. I wonder if the glfw3.dll should also be used?

Comment: GLFW has nothing to do with this.